# Find variance and expectation with given probabilities of variable values

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, variance

I've got random variable $x$ and probabilities: $P(x=0)=1/4, P(x\in[a,b])=\cfrac{b-a}{2}, P(x=3)=1/4$ where $1\leq a < b \leq 2$.

What I did:

First I tried to calculate the mathematical expectation $M(X)=0\cdot\cfrac{1}{4} + \int\limits_a^b x \cfrac{b-a}{2}dx+3\cdot \cfrac{1}{4}$. But the result seems too complicated for such a simple task. Am I getting anything wrong?

Comment: $a,b$ should not be appearing in your mean computation.  The mean should be a number, not a function of any variables.  You can compute the mean of this process mentally.

Comment: @lulu you mean it should be (3-0)/2?

Comment: Well, you need to justify that, but yes.

Comment: @lulu however I'm not sure how to calculate variance if I have both continuous and discrete distributions here

Comment: In the ordinary way.  For the discrete part you have two terms which you'll add, for the continuous part you have an integral.

Comment: @lulu but I have an integral which gives me $a$ and $b$ variables. The value of expectation is intuitive, but variance is not. The only thing is that this distribution reminds me of Uniform Distribution.

Comment: Again, $a, b$ should not appear.  The "middle" piece is $1≤x≤2$ with constant density and there is no $a,b$ in that.

Comment: @lulu The expectation when $a=1.00, b=1.01$ will not be the same as when $a=1.99, b=2.00$.

Comment: We will have two (almost) discrete distributions which are different.

Comment: No idea what that means.  What's the variance of the middle part?  Just the uniform distribution on $[1,2]$?  In other words, suppose you didn't have the discrete part.  How would you compute the variance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment section for expected value we can use
$$\mathbb{E}[X] = 0\cdot \frac{1}{4}+ \int_1^2\frac{x}{2}dx+3\cdot\frac{1}{4}$$
Try evaluate it by yourself. For variance I highly recommend you to use
$$V(X) = \Bbb E[X^2] - (\Bbb E[X])^2$$
You only need to find
$$\mathbb{E}[X^2] = 0^2\cdot \frac{1}{4}+ \int_1^2\frac{x^2}{2}dx+3^2\cdot\frac{1}{4}$$
Hope this helps!

Comment: Note: your formula (definition) for Variance is off.  Indeed, $V(X)=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$.  Also, you are missing a $\frac 12$ on both integrals,  reflecting the uniform density on $[1,2]$ (the mean of this variable is $\frac 32$ by symmetry, just as a check).